# How to store multiple form data values to a single key in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form when i submit the form the values are get stored in local storage but what i would like to do is whenever the form is submitted it should store the values in the same local storage but what happens is when i try to do the above approach it takes the last submitted value can anyone tell me how could i use the local storage to use the same key for multiple values.

```
function addToCSVFile() {
    // Collecting the names
    var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var middlename = document.getElementById('middleName').value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
    var data = {name: name, middlename: middlename, lastName: lastname};
    console.log('Data is', data);
    // alldata.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(data));
    clearData();
    alert("Data Added Successfully", JSON.stringify(data));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array and push new values to the array.

The sequence would be something like:

```
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data') || '[]');
array.push(dataObject);
localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: where is the 'dataObject' coming from?